# Actionscript - how to pass object by value?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to pass an object to a function by value so that I can make modifications to that object. I don't want the original object to be updated. However, all the function parameters are passed by reference.

I've tried to copy an object ( `var new_object:Object = original_object;` ) This just creates a pointer to `original_object`.

Is there a way I can pass parameter by value?

**update** One workaround I see is to make deep copy of an object by using `ByteArray` as [described here](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?223798-ActionScript-3-Tip-of-the-Day&p=1897368#post1897368). Not sure how efficient it is. Maybe there is a better solution out there.

Comment: The answer below is correct in that you have to clone the object to not modify the original object's fields. However, your question is not: in ActionScript, objects are *always* passed by value, never by reference. The value *is* the object you passed in, not the pointer to its container. You can verify this easily: If, at any time inside your function, you assign a different object to `original_object`, it will point to the new instance, but the original variable still points to the original object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to make a copy of the object before passing it to the function :

```
public function copy(value:Object):Object
{
    var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    buffer.writeObject(value);
    buffer.position = 0;
    var result:Object = buffer.readObject();
    return result;
}

public function testFunction(obj:Object):void
{  
   //do something with obj
}

public function test():void
{
  var obj:Object = {};
  testFunction(copy(obj));
}
```

Comment: Check out the methods `copy` and `clone` here : http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.as The `copy` I used is basically from there.

Comment: You could also do the copy inside of the testFunction(). That just makes your code a little bit easier to read wherever you call testFunction.

Comment: @BarışUşaklı - I'm a bit confused. Why can't I use copy/clone methods from  `mx.utils.ObjectUtil`? Also, when I try to include that object I don't see it in the `mx.utils` package. Is that because I need to include a library manually somehow?

Comment: @dev.e.loper if you are using Flex then you can use those functions if not you can just copy the source and add it to your project.